Complexity of single bit recovery version of Integer Factorization problem
Consider the integer factoring problem with exactly 2 prime factors $p.q=N$. Given $N$ find the prime factors $p$ and $q$. The problem is notoriously difficult (on classical computers) and is the basis of many widely used cryptographic algorithms including RSA.
Now, consider two restricted version of the problem.
Instance: Given $N$ such that it has 2 prime factors $p, q$ and $p<q$:
Problem 1: Recover the $2^{nd}$ last/least bit of smaller prime factor $p$ (instead of a complete factorization) with 100% certainty.
Problem 2: Recover the $2^{nd}$ last/least bit of smaller prime factor $p$ (instead of a complete factorization) with at most 50% one sided error. For example: If we say the bit is 1 then its 100% provably correct. But if we say the bit is 0 then there is a 50% chance of being correct.
What is the computational complexity of these 2 problems. And how are they related to the original factoring problem?
I did some search here but couldn't find an answer to this on this forum. Can someone please comment?

I'd guess this is just as hard as factoring, but I don't see a way to prove that

can someone please help?
